# How to I fix the “ModuleNotFound” error when importing PyQt5?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I’m trying to run PyQt5 but when I try to import it I get “ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘PyQt5’”. The thing is, when I go to the command terminal and enter “pip install PyQt5”, it says “Requirement already satisfied”. I use Windows 10 and PyCharm.

Comment: Are you sure pycharm uses the same python that pip uses in the CMD? Pycharm by default creates a different virtualenv than the system python

Comment: Also see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#interpreter-settings